# Grouping individuals by Q score in a structure plot in r Package LEA

Tags: r

I have completed a structure analysis on my SNP data using the LEA package in R. I have the graphical output, however, it is a jumbled mess because individuals are not arranged by Q score. Does anyone know how to group individuals along the x-axis  by Q score?

```
output = vcf2geno("kobo.vcf", "kobo.geno")

obj.at = snmf(output, K = 1:10, ploidy = 2, entropy = T,
              CPU = 2, project = "new")

qmatrix = Q(obj.at, K =9)

barplot(t(qmatrix), col = c("orange","red","green" , "blue", "pink", "yellow", "grey", "purple"), border = NA, space = 0,
        xlab = "Individuals", ylab = "Admixture coefficients")
```

This is what I get:
[image: myresults]

But I want to rearrange it so it looks somewhat like this: [image: expected results][image]

How the Qmatrix looks like

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a `dput()` of a few rows of `qmatrix`? Additionally, per the R tag (hover to see): *specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls*.

Comment: @Parfait I have added the first 6 rows of the Q matrix.  Using the recursivePackageDependencies function no dependencies were found for the LEA package.

Comment: Please include the output of `dput(head(qmatrix))` and all `library` lines in body of question. [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451) are not helpful for us. Make sure your code is compilable and runnable as is from an empty R environment (i.e., [MCVE]).

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- vector(mode="numeric", length=0)

for(i in 1:n){
  t=match(max(qmatrix[i,1],
              qmatrix[i,2],
              qmatrix[i,3],
              qmatrix[i,4],
              qmatrix[i,5]), 
             c(qmatrix[i,1],
               qmatrix[i,2],
               qmatrix[i,3],
               qmatrix[i,4],
               qmatrix[i,5]))
  x <- c(x,t)
}

qmatrix1 <- qmatrix[order(x),]
```

Comment: Please explain your otherwise code-only answer. Its effect and why that solves the problem.